# Mysql Insert from another table and count records

Tags: mysql

I want to know how many 'users' will be inserted into 'ladder'

Thats what i got:

```
INSERT INTO ladder (id, text, createdAt)
    SELECT id, text, createdAt
    FROM users
    WHERE invisible=0
    AND createdAt >= $today
    LIMIT $maxValue
```

Thanks for help:)

Comment: maybe none. Who knows.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: the select subquery will return from 0 to $maxvalue records. Then, can I teach you one almost unknown and advanced tecnique for programming. It's called testing. It means: open the db and try to run the query against data: you will discover a fantastic news. Guess what? the answer to this question!!! First you run the subquery and the the query.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> If you use an INSERT ... VALUES statement with multiple value lists or
>   INSERT ... SELECT, the statement returns an information string in this
>   format:
>
> Records: 100 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 Records indicates the number of
>   rows processed by the statement. (This is not necessarily the number
>   of rows actually inserted because Duplicates can be nonzero.)
>   Duplicates indicates the number of rows that could not be inserted
>   because they would duplicate some existing unique index value.
>   Warnings indicates the number of attempts to insert column values that
>   were problematic in some way.